# Table Value Change issue with using Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, vaadin

Using `Java Vaadin FrameWork`, I want to link from a column selected from the NewsAndEvents table to the column in the Document table below. So when I select one of the columns in the table above, I want the columns with the same ForeignKey to come up. 
`if (selectedItem != null)` I need to create another if within the block, and this time I need to get two entities with the same ID. I mentioned the relationship between Entities below and the valueChange method of the table with you.Can the section I comment on work?

**NewsAndEvents Entity**

```
@Transient
private Document document;
```

**Documents Entity**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="news_and_events_id" ,foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK_docu_cpt_nae"))
private NewsAndEvents newsAndEvents;

@Column(name = "news_and_events_id", nullable=true,scale=0, precision=19, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long newsAndEventsFk;
```

**Table ValueChange metod**

```
table.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        NewsAndEvents selectedItem = (NewsAndEvents) event.getProperty().getValue();
            if (selectedItem != null) {

                //if(selectedItem.getDocument().getNewsAndEventsFk() == selectedItem.getId())


                addNewDocumentButton.setEnabled(selectedItem != null);
                deleteButton.setEnabled(selectedItem != null);
                editButton.setEnabled(selectedItem != null);
            } else {
                deleteDocumentButton.setEnabled(selectedItem != null);
                deleteButton.setEnabled(selectedItem != null);
                editButton.setEnabled(selectedItem != null);
            }
    }

});
```